# Where are the different Spider-men in this image from?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, spider-man

I'm trying to identify the different Spider-men in this image:

[image]

### Where are the different Spider-men in this image from?

Comment: Man, I could totally have answered this but for the fastness of the GIF. Any way we could get an image showing them separately.

Comment: @RedCaio - 50 frames, of which 2 are the start and end, according to the page I used.

Comment: Side note:  Is it "Spider-Men" or "Spider-Mans"?

Comment: Where is this image from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are the names you are looking:

[image]

Artist [Salvador Anguian](https://www.behance.net/gallery/22328711/Spider-Man-History)o (who also made a chart featuring 75 years of Batman's cowl) created this chart that includes the incarnations of Spider-Man's mask over a period of fifty-two years.

Comment: Aw man, I was half way thru my answer going off of memory but this is perfect. [sighs] I'm abandoning my answer. [cries] +1

Comment: @RedCaio i am sorry buddy it was too easy to find but u did a great job splitting the frames

Comment: So, I'm guessing you did a reverse image search or a visually similar image search, right?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I did. I knew some of them but google image search came in handy.